# pandas groupby multiple columns with python and streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, streamlit

I  have a **groupby** function that i want to group multiple columns in order to plot a chart later.
The dataframe's columns are dynamic where user select it from a `selectbox` and `multiselect` widgets
The problem is that i am able now just to take the first or the last item from the `multiselect` widget like so:

```
 some_columns_df = df.loc[:,['gender','country','city','hoby','company','status']]
 some_collumns = some_columns_df.columns.tolist()

 select_box_var= st.selectbox("Choose X Column",some_collumns)
 multiselect_var= st.multiselect("Select Columns To GroupBy",some_collumns)  

 test_g3 = df.groupby([select_box_var,multiselect_var[0]]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

**if user select more than 1 item from the `multiselect` let say he choose 4 item it becomes like below:**

```
 test_g3 = df.groupby([select_box_var,multiselect_var[0,1,2,3]]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

is this possible ?

Comment: I would try not indexing into `multiselect_var` at all. What does `print(multiselect_var)` show?

Comment: @PaulH it shows the selected items by the user like if he choose **gender** and **status**  it will display both of them  as dictionary like so:[
`0:
"gender"
1:
"status"
]`

Comment: Strange. What's the output of `print(type(multiselect_var))`?

Comment: @PaulH sorry for the mistake its a **list** not a **dictionary**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From streamlit docs for multiselect [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.multiselect), the api returns a list always. And your selectbox returns a string as you have a list of strings as option.

So your code can be modified to,

```
df.groupby([select_box_var] + multiselect_var).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: how can i use this to plot a chart ?
i tried this :
`fig = px.bar(test_g3,x=[select_box_var], y='count' ,color = multiselect_var,barmode = 'group')` but return the below error:
`ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `color` is 2, whereas the length of previously-processed arguments ['count', 'gender'] is 51`

Answer (score 1):

`multiselect_var` is a list while `select_box_var` is a single variable. Put it inside a list and add both lists together.

Try this:

```
 test_g3 = df.groupby([select_box_var] + multiselect_var).size().reset_index(name='count')
```